# On Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

For a set A of real numbers $(A \subset \mathbb{R}) $, define outer measure of set A as, $ m^*(A) = \inf \{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l (I_k)/A\subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k\}. $ I want to find the outer measure of set $(2,5) $ by using of definition of outer measure. How to apply definition of outer measure? (I know outer measure of an interval is its length but i want to know how to use definition of outer measure to calculate outer measure of given set)

Comment: If you read the proof that outer measure of an interval is just its length, there they will explicitly show how to pick the cover to give you the result.

Comment: What is needed is the interesting but nontrivial fact: if you cover $(2,5)$ by any sequence of intervals, then the sum of the lengths is at least $7$.  (To do this, I would use the Heine-Borel theorem.)